# PUSH and POP out of DWORD in Assembly x86

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

So far I tried several ways to print the values in DWORD, but I only get either the first or last digit, and I would need to print all 5 digits in reverse order.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

arr1 DWORD 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx,4
    mov esi,0
L1:
    mov eax,arr1[esi]

    push eax 
    sub esi,4
    loop L1
    mov ecx,4   
    mov esi,0
L2:     pop eax
    mov arr1[esi],eax
    add esi,4
    loop L2
    mov esi,OFFSET arr1
    mov ecx,4
L3:
    mov eax,[esi+ecx*4]

    call WriteDec
    sub ecx,4
    call EndLine
    loop L3
    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the `Stack` is [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29), meaning the last value you pushed onto the stack is the first value popped off, right?

If you do:

```
push    2
push    4
push    6
push    8
push    10
```

Then the first value popped off the stack is 10, then 8, then 6, etc.  So 10 will get printed first.

We can get rid of a lot of your code, since you just want to print the values in reverse order with `pop`.

```
main PROC
    mov     ecx, 5
    mov     esi, 0
L1:
    push    arr1[esi]   
    add     esi, 4      ; add 4 to arr1 pointer
    loop    L1          ; loop until ecx == 0

    mov     ecx, 5      ; reset loop counter
L3:
    pop     eax
    call    WriteDec
    call    Crlf
    loop    L3

    call    Crlf
    call    WaitMsg
    exit
main ENDP
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so much now it makes sense, I was doing extra steps. I really appreciate your help